# Update document and nested document in the same update

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

Say I had a document like the following:

```
doc = { 'A':1,
        'B':2,
        'C':3}
```

here I want to update `B` and `C` where `A` corresponds to some value, hence:

```
db.collection.update_one(
                        {"A": 1},
                        {"$set": {"B":4,'C':5}})
```

But what if the document has a nested document in it? Can I update both values at the same time?

```
doc = { 'A':1,
        'B':2,
        'C':{'D':3}}
```

In this case, how would I overwrite both `A`, and in this case `D`, in the same update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a field in an embedded document, use dot notation:

```
db.collection.update_one({"A": 1},
                         {"$set": {"B": 4, "C.D": 5}})
```

More info:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents

Comment: Nice one, the mongo help does a great job of throwing me of the scent, Thanks for your help